# How to add div in wordpress testemonials plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this plugin for testimonials  [testimonials](https://wordpress.org/plugins/testimonials-widget/) and i want to add my custom div foreach testimonial.I found this [example](https://nodedesk.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202244572-How-do-I-customize-my-testimonial-list-and-widget-output-) for editing view of plugin,but i still dont understand how it work.So how can i add it?

Comment: where to add the div? your can filter that function

Comment: for example i want to add badge foreach testimonial inside of testimonial block.How can i filter it?Can you please write me an example?

Comment: ok I will try to do this

Comment: okay,it will be cool

Answer (score 0):

In your theme `function.php`  add the bellow code and change the image `url` with your image url `http://www.subway.com/core/images/topNavBar/subway-logo.png`

**Code**

```
 add_filter( 'testimonials_widget_testimonial_html', 'my_testimonials_widget_testimonial_html', 10, 5 );

function my_testimonials_widget_testimonial_html( $content, $testimonial, $atts, $is_list = true, $is_first = false, $widget_number = null ) {

    echo'<div class="my-image"><img width="98%" class="custom-image" src="http://www.subway.com/core/images/topNavBar/subway-logo.png" alt="" /></div>';


    return $content;
}
```

Comment: where to display... in slider or recent testimonials ?

Comment: i am using this function testimonials() in testimonials.php file,which is template for testimonial page created in wordpress.It is not a slider.